# A variable value altered when I insert a print statement?

Tags: c

I am dealing with arrays of 10 variables. I am calculating cross correlation. When I insert a printf statement (last two lines from the return 0) to include the value being returned, sxy's value from 2nd iteration onward is altered (put 2 of them in bold).  See the values I get - without the printf statement:

```
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = -0.441021, denom=0.944295
-5       -0.467037
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = **-0.232003**, denom=0.944295
-4       -0.245689
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = **0.066825**, denom=0.944295
-3       0.070767
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = -0.080936, denom=0.944295
-2       -0.085711
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = 0.304371, denom=0.944295
-1       0.322326
```

Just by including the printf statement:

```
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = -0.441021, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = **-0.341112**, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = **-0.064583**, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = -0.085263, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = 0.333693, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = 0.625614, denom=0.944295
sxy = 0.000000
sxy = 0.074215, denom=0.944295
```

Here is the code:

```
int cxcor(float x[], float y[], float r[])
{
   /* Calculate the mean of the two series x[], y[] */
   int i, j, delay, maxdelay = MAXM/2, n = MAXM;
   float sx, sxy, mx = 0;
   float sy, denom, my = 0;   
   float rr[MAXM];

   for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
      mx += x[i];
      my += y[i];
   }
   mx /= n;
   my /= n;

   /* Calculate the denominator */
   sx = 0;
   sy = 0;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
      sx += (x[i] - mx) * (x[i] - mx);
      sy += (y[i] - my) * (y[i] - my);
   }
   denom = sqrt(sx*sy);

   /* Calculate the correlation series */
   for (delay = -maxdelay; delay < maxdelay; delay++) {
      sxy = 0;
      printf ("sxy = %f \n", sxy );
      for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
         j = i + delay;
         while (j < 0)
            j += n;
         j %= n;
         sxy += (x[i] - mx) * (y[j] - my);
      }
      printf ("sxy = %f, denom=%f\n", sxy, denom);
      tr = sxy / denom;
      k = delay;
      r[ k] = tr;
      printf ("%d\t %f\n", k, r[k]);


   }


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly indicates [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere in your code.

It could be due to reading an uninitialized variables or reading/writing past the end of an array.

If you can't find the issue by examining the code, using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on it might be a good strategy.

Comment: What do u mean by 'out-of-bounds access"?

Comment: Normally, that means if you have an array `int x[10]`, you are accessing `x[-1]`, `x[10]`, or other elements that are outside the valid range of the array.

Comment: I have eliminated the negative subscript now. I then found the maximum of the ten values and am passing it back to the main. However, main() is not receiving it. So in addition, I used "return rmax" and it works correctly. max is float on both end. Why is this the case? What should I do to successfully pass the rmax through the function? float   cxcor(float x[], float y[],   float rmax)

Answer (score 0):

These lines are the main problem:

```
k = delay;
r[ k] = tr;
```

because `delay` ranges from `-maxm/2` to `+maxm/2`
and negative offsets from an array (for instance `r[-maxm/2]`) 
will step on memory (the stack) that is in memory 
before the definition of `r[]`.
That is what is corrupting the values.

This kind of action, where a memory address outside an array bounds
is stepped on is undefined behaviour 
and can/will lead to a seg fault event

suggest:

```
k = delay+(maxm/2);
r[ k] = tr;
```

Also, this algorithm with produce inaccurate results
when `maxm` is odd.

Comment: I added those lines because of the issue itself. I added those lines to try and eliminate the issue. I tried to shift the indexes. I had it as rr as a local variable whereas r was being passed on by the function call. r and rr were giving different values as described earlier. If I calculate r first, the values are correct. It might still be the same issue you are talking about.

Comment: memmove() is any good - I tried but could not. Are u saying that the  subscript/index should never be negative ... because it is invalid?

Comment: @user4504270 you can't access outside the bounds of an array. check that `k` is within the range of `0` up to however big `r` is (your code doesn't show that) before writing `r[k]`.

Comment: If r is being passed via the function int cxcor(float x[], float y[], float r[]), from main(), then r's dimensions may not be set right? I have an include file with the dimension of r.